# Best use case and example of the clusters in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

As I am going through with the topic of the clusters and still a little confused about the best use-case of clusters.
can anyone help and example of the use-case of the same.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS processes runs on a single process, which means it does not take advantage from multi-core systems by default. If you have an 8 core CPU and run a NodeJS program via $ node app.js it will run in a single process, wasting the rest of CPUs.

NodeJS offers the cluster module that contains a set of functions and properties that help us to create programs that uses all the CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Cluster can be viewed as **Load-Balance** built in node itself, that can make use of the multi CPU's in the system.

If you don't use the cluster, '*node*' will be using single CPU and will have a bit of performance impact.

When you are running your Node as a Middleware (Express Server) to serve API's request, you will see the advantage of Cluster where the request can be served by the different clusters working on different CPU's, resulting in better performance.

**Side Note**: Using cluster, you can also make sure that your node server never gets killed by any Uncaught exception (though this condition should have been handled), i.e., if one of the cluster gets killed, you can handle that condition and create new cluster node and make sure your serer is up and running always.

```
let numWorkers = require('os').cpus().length;
for (let i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

// if one of the worker died, create new one immediately
cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
        console.log('Starting a new worker');
        cluster.fork();
    });

cluster.on('online', function (worker) {
    console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
});
```